# Does Flink have the minPartitions setting for Kafka like Spark?

Tags: apache-flink

In Spark, there's the `minPartitions` setting. Here's what it's for as per documentation:

```
Desired minimum number of partitions to read from Kafka. By default, Spark has a 1-1 
mapping of topicPartitions to Spark partitions consuming from Kafka. If you set this 
option to a value greater than your topicPartitions, Spark will divvy up large Kafka 
partitions to smaller pieces. Please note that this configuration is like a hint: the 
number of Spark tasks will be approximately minPartitions. It can be less or more 
depending on rounding errors or Kafka partitions that didn't receive any new data.
```

Does Flink feature anything similar? I read that there's the `KafkaPartitionSplit`, but how do you use that?

The documentation also says this:

```
Source Split #
A source split in Kafka source represents a partition of Kafka topic. A Kafka source split consists of:

TopicPartition the split representing
Starting offset of the partition
**Stopping offset of the partition, only available when the source is running in bounded mode**
```

Does splitting the source like this only make sense when processing historical data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Kafka source in the Flink workflow has a parallelism, which defines how many sub-tasks (each running in a separate slot) will be used to read from your Kafka topic. Flink hashes the topic name to pick the first sub-task that's assigned partition 0, and then continues (in a round-robin manner) to assign partitions to sub-tasks.

So you typically want to set your source parallelism such that the number of partitions is a multiple of the parallelism. E.g. if you have 40 partitions, set your parallelism to 40, or 20, or 10, such that each sub-task is processing the same number of partitions (and thus mitigate data skew issues).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I'm talking about. I'm talking about having, e.g. 40 partitions in a Kafka topic and 120 tasks in Flink. This is what Spark does with minPartitions. This is because, when you have a lot of data in Kafka, you can read each partition in parallel. Say, in one partition you have startOffset = 0, and endOffset = 1000. You can have 5 tasks reading data from that 1 partition, the first task has offsets (0-200), second (201-400), third (401-600) etc.

Comment: Note that this is about parallelizing reading and it's not the same as reading 40 partitions with 40 tasks and then increasing parallelism to 120.

Comment: Flink doesn't support reading from one partition in parallel with multiple sub-tasks. The minimum unit of work for a sub-task is one partition. You can of course increase the downstream parallelism of the next operator, but that will trigger a network rebalance, which can be expensive.

Comment: I see, thank you. That sucks though, would be awesome if Flink had this. Why does KafkaParitionSplit exist then?

Comment: Talked to David Anderson, he said that he sees no use in having this in Flink, because for batch processing you can define several Sources with different offsets for the same topic, and for streaming where lag between Flink and Kafka is small it seems to be overkill, and isn't worth it. I agree with him.